# Issue with cancelling the AlarmManager - PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I have an app which reminds people to do their tasks. So there is one PendingIntent, now the user can delete the alarm when he wants to. In this code, there is just one PendingIntent for multiple user alarms so I am confused on cancelling that particular alarm where the intent extras is `"pill"`. The remaining alarms should not be cancelled. I have no clue on this problem. Hope I am clear. Thanks

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmNotifyReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra("Name_pill", "pill");
sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
DatabaseConstants.NOTIFICATION_ID + 1, intent,
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
updateTheFlag(pillName[(pillName.length-1)]);
```

Comment: I am also looking for a similar answer to this question.  I'm doing something very similar to you, but I cannot seem to get it working.  My understanding right now is that you need to use am.cancel(pendingIntent) meaning you would need to initialize an identical pendingIntent to the one you made here.  However, that does not seem to work for me.  Anyone who can answer this one will surely get an upvote from me :)

Answer (score 13):

According to the Android documentation, in order to stop an alarm, you should create an `Intent` with the same data, but *not* necessarily the same extras:

> public void cancel (PendingIntent operation)
>
> Remove any alarms with a matching Intent. Any alarm, of any type, whose Intent matches this > one (as defined by *filterEquals(Intent)*), will be canceled.

`filterEquals(Intent)`

> public boolean filterEquals (Intent other)
>
> Determine if two intents are the same for the purposes of intent resolution (filtering). > That is, if their action, data, type, class, and categories are the same. **This does not compare any extra data included in the intents.**

Comment: So if you have 2 `PendingIntent`'s, created at different times which do the exact same thing, what should be used to differentiate them?

Answer (score 5):

As I stated in my comment, it appears that you simply need to recreate the exact same PendingIntent object, and put the same Extras into it.  Then, you call

```
am.cancel(sender);
```

And your specific alarm should be canceled.  I can't find a better way of doing it, personally.  I found this information to confirm my expectation [elsewhere](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/tag/alarmmanager/).

It reads:

> Repeating alarms have to be cancelled to stop them. AlarmManager provide a cancel() method that requires the same intent class with which the intent is created. This is how you can cancel the alarm.
>
> alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
>
> Note the pendingIntent object does not need to be same object. The intent fields like action, class, category etc should be same while creating the alarm. The intent is used to identify the alarm to cancel it.

It is in the context of repeating alarms, but one-time alarms should be canceled in the same manner, if I am not mistaken.  I am unable to test it more thoroughly on my own because I am at work, but this should work.

Comment: according to the Android documentation, in order to stop an alarm, you should create an `Intent` with the same data, but NOT necessarily the same extras: public void cancel (PendingIntent operation)
Remove any alarms with a matching Intent. Any alarm, of any type, whose Intent matches this one (as defined by filterEquals(Intent)), will be canceled.

Answer (score 1):

I think the *requestCode* parameter in `getBroadcast()` needs to be mentioned. I agree that all the alarms will be canceled matching with the given Intent. But an alarm can be made to be unique by using unique *requestCode* when defining the *PendingIntent* for canceling. So only those alarms will be canceled which has the same *intent* and *requestCode*:

```
int TIMER_1 = 1;
int TIMER_2 = 2;
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(this, AppReciever.class);
i.putExtra("timer", "one");
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, TIMER_1, i,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pending);
```

then check that the PendingIntent exist according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15047197/1342413):

```
PendingIntent pending1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, TIMER_2, i, 
                PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
boolean alarmUp = (pending1 != null);
```

`alarmUp` will be *false* (note FLAG_NO_CREATE is used not to create a new one if not exist) so trying with same *requestCode*:

```
PendingIntent pending2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, TIMER_1, i, 
                PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
alarmUp = (pending2 != null);
```

`alarmUp` will be *true*, now trying with a new intent contains different extra:

```
Intent i2 = new Intent(this, AppReciever.class);
i2.putExtra("timer", "two");
pending2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, TIMER_1, i2, 
                PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
alarmUp = (pending2 != null);
```

`alarmUp` will be *true* as well since the `i` and `i2` are the same although the extra is not, so now you can remove this alarm:

```
am.cancel(pending2);
```

Answer (score 0):

> So there is one pending intent,now the user can delete the alram when
>   he wants to. Ib this code there is just one pending intent for
>   multiple user alarms so I am confused on cancelling that particular
>   alarm where extras is pill

```
intent.putExtra("Name_pill", "pill");
```

The extra wont wont work to  cancel your pending intent .

`pendingIntent.cancel()` will only remove that pending intent which triggered with same `filterEquals(Intent)`  and that method is not compare any extra data given to intent .

this is the contain from developer site of android `filterEquals(Intent)`

> Determine if two intents are the same for the purposes of intent
>   resolution (filtering). That is, if their action, data, type, class,
>   and categories are the same. This does not compare any extra data
>   included in the intents.

if we consider your scenario , when you will pass that `Extra` to intent at that time   you only need to save unique ID in some `sharedpreference`  which given in parameter and one thing your should keep in mind that ID has to be an unique .

and  and when you suppose to cancel that alarm , just pass same intent with  that saved ID and cancel that `pendingintent` .

> Create

```
preference_saved_value =  DatabaseConstants.NOTIFICATION_ID + 1
sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
preference_saved_value, intent,
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

> CANCEL

```
sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 
preference_saved_value, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);  
sender.cancel()
```

Answer (score 0):

As it's stated in android documentation pending intents with intent that are equivalent as per Intent.filterEquals but have different request code are considered different:

> If you truly need multiple distinct PendingIntent objects active at
>   the same time (such as to use as two notifications that are both shown
>   at the same time), then you will need to ensure there is something
>   that is different about them to associate them with different
>   PendingIntents. This may be any of the Intent attributes considered by
>   Intent.filterEquals, or different request code integers supplied to
>   getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int), getActivities(Context, int,
>   Intent[], int), getBroadcast(Context, int, Intent, int), or
>   getService(Context, int, Intent, int).

So, you can assign different request code and cancel the pending intents base on them and forget about the extra.

There was an interesting scenario that I figured out this behavior:

I scheduled an alarm in my code and run it on the device but never canceled it. Then I changed the request code and run it again. So a new alarm was created. I canceled the new alarm but the alarm was still executing from previous code. I get confused why the alarm is not canceled. After I found out it's from the previous code with different request code I uninstalled the app and installed it again and problem was solved.