# Unable to tell if alarm is scheduled- repeating alarm

Tags: android, scheduling, alarmmanager, alarm

I have a repeating alarm that is started in the class StartActivity. The package is psychsoft.gps.v1 The code does not seem to catch whether the alarm is started or not.

```
        if ((PendingIntent.getBroadcast(con, 13336,
            new Intent("psychsoft.gps.v1"), 
            PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null))
    {
        Log.i("aaa", "Alarm is already active");
        Toast.makeText(con, "alarm already active", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }



    Calendar calGPS = Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent intentGPS = new Intent(con, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intentGPS.putExtra("alarm_message", "gps");
    PendingIntent senderGPS = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 13336, intentGPS, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);        
    // Get the AlarmManager service
    AlarmManager amGPS = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    amGPS.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calGPS.getTimeInMillis(),1000*60*5, senderGPS);
```

To test this code I run it once to schedule the alarm (installing the app). Then I run it again (by clicking the icon) to try to get the Toast, or Log output. I am getting neither. Why? I originally though the issue might be fixed by matching the request code of the PendingIntent to that of the if statement, but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Here check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9575569 for a good example how to do what you want to achieve.  Then in that example if alarmup is false, create your intent and schedule your alarm again.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating and checking the intent like this instead:

```
Intent intentGPS = new Intent("psychsoft.gps.v1.MY_UNIQUE_ACTION");
```

and

```
if ((PendingIntent.getBroadcast(con, 13336,
            new Intent("psychsoft.gps.v1.MY_UNIQUE_ACTION"), 
            PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null))
    {
        Log.i("aaa", "Alarm is already active");
        Toast.makeText(con, "alarm already active", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: In that case the intent would look like this: Intent intentGPS = new Intent("psychsoft.gps.v1.AlarmReceiver"); Is that correct?

Comment: To clarify my earlier comment: what is MY_UNIQUE_ACTION in your code? Is the class (AlarmReceiver) or is it something else?