# alarm manager service starting every oncreate

Tags: android

I am using an alarm manager with  `inexactRepeating` starting a `pendingIntent`.

Works great - only problem is that the service is running every time the app is started, after `onDestroy` (ie orientation change, manually swiping app in recent).

I have it set to 20 min intervals, and it does so as long as I dont onDestroy the app - the `onCreate` automatically starts the service which screws up my timing. The service is only ever called, once, through the alarm manager.

How do I check to see if the app needs to run it? Boolean of is running inside the service in shared preferences or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer was on this site at this link:

[How to check if AlarmManager already has an alarm set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556670/how-to-check-if-alarmmamager-already-has-an-alarm-set)

The idea is to use a boolean to determine if the alarm has already been set:

```
        boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, MyApp.TIMER_1, i, 
                          PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
```

Comment: Or use the singleton advice below - I would have, if this app was extensive enough to require me to use a singleton.

Answer (score 2):

You could place the `AlarmManager` in a class that your [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class creates once during application startup.  Then you will ensure that your app only creates one instance of the `AlarmManager` when it first starts up.

In other words, create a class that extends `Application`, and in its onCreate(), create an instance of your AlarmManager class and store that instance in that Application class.  Inside the class that holds your AlarmManager, in its constructor create a new instance of AlarmManager.  Then in your `Application` class, you could create a getter method so that any of your app's other activities or fragments could retrieve and use that one instance of AlarmManager.

Note that there is some [debate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826905/singletons-vs-application-context-in-android) as to whether you should use the `Application` class to store global application state, as opposed to a static singleton.

Comment: It's a possibility, but is it really not too much overhead? I am using the repeatingservice to record sensor data at regular intervals, and I just need the service to start, and not to run every time the service is running. Thanks for the excellent explanation and unbiased mentioning of the debate- everyone ought to consider it.