# android execute code only once

Tags: android, alarmmanager

i am having an application where i need to schedule an alarm for every fifteen minute this is the code

```
public void scheduleAlarm() {
    // Construct an intent that will execute the AlarmReceiver
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyAlarmReceiver.class);
    // Create a PendingIntent to be triggered when the alarm goes off
    final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, MyAlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    // Setup periodic alarm every 5 seconds
    long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); // alarm is set right away
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    // First parameter is the type: ELAPSED_REALTIME, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, RTC_WAKEUP
    // Interval can be INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, INTERVAL_HOUR, INTERVAL_DAY
    alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis,
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, pIntent);
  }
}
```

and i will call this method in the onCreate method of my mainActivity, my problem is i am not getting how to restrict the method being called only once since the onCreate method will be called everytime the activity is created. If i use a sharedpreference to store whether the method is called or not, what to do if the user clear the appdata from settings.

Comment: even google cant help if the user cleared the app data; hope u got the answer :) ; have fun coding

Comment: @Shantanu Hi just check with this questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462279/alarm-manager-service-starting-every-oncreate.

Comment: then store the info in local database

Comment: there is no sure way to get rid of this. if the user clears the prefs, it will fire again. also a database can be cleared by a root user, but it decreases the possible users.

Comment: if you REALLY want to execute code for just once per user, you can pull counter from online server (with login) and use this to trigger code only once.

Comment: @Dexter i did not get what you mean by a counter, do you mean to use a get/post method to set and reset a flag at the server. thanks

Comment: @Shaan_B , yes. If it is very important, you can write code in such way that it will work only when you get flag from online server. You just change flag after code execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one Prefrence and set flag in to it.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                                editor.putBoolean("isFlag", false);
                                editor.commit();
```

Before call this method check he flag, if it is true then your method will called.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isFlag", true)) {
    scheduleAlarm();
}
```

I hope it may help you...

Comment: You can create your own Activity like **RestrictClearData.java**
And in this Activity set an Error message like.."You dont have an permition to clear app data"

just add single line in to your Application tag in manifest file.
**android:manageSpaceActivity=".RestrictClearData"**

Comment: Instead of **Clear Data** button **Manage Space** Button will appeared. if user click on this then Restrict user Acticity will call.


I hope it may helps you.. :)

Comment: Okey.. If you asked this question then you can accept my answer.
also you can increase your reputation to accepting my answer.