# Android: how to know when an alarm is triggered

Tags: android, sqlite, android-alarms

I am trying to follow these steps on how to manage alarms and I need help!

Having a SQLite table etc. to properly track alarms, along with created,scheduled and triggered time stamps.

Here on in an answer on stackoverflow: [AlarmMenager Checking if alarm already fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27570940/alarmmenager-checking-if-alarm-already-fired#answer-27572540)

So I have created my alarm to fire on specific days, which actually works. I insert the SQLite when alarm was set and other details.

But my issue is I need to update the Table in SQLite when the alarm precisely triggered. To update the "`triggered_at`" column.

This is my below code that Fires ze alarm!

```
        //Alarm Manager Set

        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReminderAlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);


        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 5); // 5 is Thursday
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4); // 4 is 4:00AM HOUR
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 48); // 48 is 48 minutes
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);


        /* Insert SQLite data */
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTable (Name VARCHAR, Repeating INT, time FLOAT, alarm_set_at INT, triggered_at INT)");

        //Get current time and other details and replace the static values
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ('Brimelow', 1, 18:00, 1780094, 1800094); ");


/** After Alarm has been triggered **/
db.execSQL("UPDATE MyTable SET triggered_at = 'TIME_TRIGGERED' ");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `BroadcastReceiver` (ReminderAlarmReceiver.class) when you handle your `alarmIntent` you can update column `triggered_at`.