# How does android compare pending intents

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

Documentation for [PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_NO_CREATE) reads:

> Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent does not already exist, then simply return null instead of creating it.

My question: **What criteria are used to compare PendingIntents?**

I'm guessing under the hood this flag uses [PendingIntent.equals](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/59701b9ba5c453e327bc0e6873a9f6ff87a10391/core/java/android/app/PendingIntent.java#L915), but I'm not really sure what criteria that function is using.  Is it using the action, requestCode, categories, extras (I'm guessing no), etc.?

Context:

I want to start an alarm with a pending intent if my alarm is not already setup.  Specifically, I'm following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556670/how-to-check-if-alarmmanager-already-has-an-alarm-set/9575569#9575569).

```
Intent i = new Intent(applicationContext, MyService.class);
i.setAction("myAction");
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(applicationContext, /*requestCode*/0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
if (pi != null) {
  AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
  alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR, pi);
}
```

Comment: Nice question.   
I know this is not right.   
But, I used to cancel previous alarm and restart it when ever i think it was needed.. I am looking forward to this question's answer.

Comment: I guess its requestCode only. Can't you access the source to check it? Android Studio usually does show it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To determine if 2 `PendingIntent`s match, the following must be equal:

- The `requestCode` parameter used when the `PendingIntent` was created
- The `Intent` ACTION
- The `Intent` CATEGORIES
- The `Intent` DATA
- The `Intent` MIMETYPE
- The `Intent` PACKAGE
- The `Intent` COMPONENT

Extras are not taken into consideration.

You can read more in the [PendingIntent summary documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) and [Intent.filterEquals()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals(android.content.Intent)).

Answer (score 2):

> I'm guessing under the hood this flag uses PendingIntent.equals, but
> I'm not really sure what criteria that function is using. Is it using
> the action, requestCode, categories, extras (I'm guessing no), etc.?

Actually the hint is in class description:

> A description of an Intent and target action to perform with it.
> Instances of this class are created with
>
> getActivity(android.content.Context,int,android.content.Intent,int),
> getActivities(android.content.Context,int,android.content.Intent[],int),
> getBroadcast(android.content.Context,int,android.content.Intent,int),
> getService(android.content.Context,int,android.content.Intent,int);
>
> the returned object can be handed to other applications so that they
> can perform the action you described on your behalf at a later time.
>
> By giving a PendingIntent to another application, you are granting it
> the right to perform the operation you have specified as if the other
> application was yourself (with the same permissions and identity). As
> such, you should be careful about how you build the PendingIntent:
> almost always, for example, the base Intent you supply should have the
> component name explicitly set to one of your own components, to ensure
> it is ultimately sent there and nowhere else.
>
> A PendingIntent itself
> is simply a reference to a token maintained by the system describing
> the original data used to retrieve it. This means that, even if its
> owning application's process is killed, the PendingIntent itself will
> remain usable from other processes that have been given it. If the
> creating application later re-retrieves the same kind of PendingIntent
> (same operation, same Intent action, data, categories, and components,
> and same flags), it will receive a PendingIntent representing the same
> token if that is still valid, and can thus call cancel() to remove it.
>
> Because of this behavior, it is important to know when two Intents are
> considered to be the same for purposes of retrieving a PendingIntent.
> A common mistake people make is to create multiple PendingIntent
> objects with Intents that only vary in their "extra" contents,
> expecting to get a different PendingIntent each time. This does not
> happen. The parts of the Intent that are used for matching are the
> same ones defined by Intent.filterEquals. If you use two Intent
> objects that are equivalent as per Intent.filterEquals, then you will
> get the same PendingIntent for both of them.
>
> There are two typical ways to deal with this.
>
> If you truly need multiple distinct
> PendingIntent objects active at the same time (such as to use as two
> notifications that are both shown at the same time), then you will
> need to ensure there is something that is different about them to
> associate them with different PendingIntents. This may be any of the
> Intent attributes considered by Intent.filterEquals, or different
> request code integers supplied to
> getActivity(android.content.Context,int,android.content.Intent,int),
> getActivities(android.content.Context,int,android.content.Intent[],int),
> getBroadcast(android.content.Context,int,android.content.Intent,int),
> or getService(android.content.Context,int,android.content.Intent,int).
>
> If you only need one PendingIntent active at a time for any of the
> Intents you will use, then you can alternatively use the flags
> FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT or FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT to either cancel or modify
> whatever current PendingIntent is associated with the Intent you are
> supplying.

from:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/android/app/PendingIntent.java#PendingIntent

Comment: I'm asking what this function does: "I'm guessing under the hood this flag uses [PendingIntent.equals](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/59701b9ba5c453e327bc0e6873a9f6ff87a10391/core/java/android/app/PendingIntent.java#L915), but I'm not really sure what criteria that function is using"

Comment: Usually people watch source to understand sucj things and thats why i'm showing it to you.

Comment: I usually appreciate source code in an answer!  It's usually great to help explain/support an answer.  But I pasted a link to exactly the code you pasted.  I don't understand that code, so I'm looking for an explanation, not just a copy/past of code that I linked to.

Comment: Sorry, I din't noticed the link to a method. I was expecting to see its body in your question.

Comment: The answer is buried in your ~30 lines of quoted text.  If you format it I'll give your the check.

Comment: You could just visit the url.

Comment: Ok, I'll write an appropriate answer myself.

Comment: It is formatted well enough? Cuz its like on a grepcode without links.