# Android - Are Pending Intents Cancelled

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

Thanks to the good folks here, I have learned that any alarms set are cancelled when a device boots down. However, I am curious if the pending intents that are sent to the alarms are destroyed as well? For example, would some implementation of the code noted here: [How to check if AlarmManager already has an alarm set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556670/how-to-check-if-alarmmanager-already-has-an-alarm-set) be suitable to reset alarms if they are cancelled due to a reboot (basically would a call to getBroadcast and  PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE return null after reboot)?

Thanks so much!

Comment: "(basically would a call to getBroadcast and PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE return null after reboot)?" - Yes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!