# How to make a function to check statement of AlarmManager in Android?

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager

I have a class to turn on the `AlarmManager`. I want to call my `startMonitoring` only when the `AlarmManager` does not start. The below functions are to start and stop the `AlarmManager`, but they do not have functions to checking the `AlarmManager` is starting/stopping (statement). How can I make a function check it?

```
public static class MonitorBR extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onReceive : MonitorBR");
        if (ServiceUtil.isRunningService(context, ReadService.class) == false) {           
            context.startService(new Intent(context, ReadService.class));                  
        }
    }
}


public void setInterval(long interval) {
    this.interval = interval;
}


public void startMonitoring(Context context) {
    am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    intent = new Intent(context, MonitorBR.class);
    sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), interval, sender);

public void stopMonitoring(Context context) {
    am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    intent = new Intent(context, MonitorBR.class);
    sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    am.cancel(sender);
    am = null;
    sender = null;
}
```

Comment: You can use preferences to save boolean when start/stop alarm. And after that you can check value in your new method.

Comment: Maybe this would help,check it out:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9575569/7007542