# AlarmManager and notifications - notifications don't display, alarm fires when it shouldn't

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm developing my first android app for a client. The launch is scheduled on Saturday, everything works all right... but one thing.

I need the app to connect to the client's website **once every 3 days**, download events' info, then show a notification and (in some cases) send an email.

What is happening right now is that the app doesn't show any notification, but sends multiple mails every day instead: that should mean that the Alarm fires multiple times per day instead of once every 3.

In my manifest, i have these two receivers:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

[...]

<receiver android:name=".Helper.AlarmDownload"/>
    <receiver
        android:name=".Helper.AlarmBootReceiver"
        android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**AlarmDownload.java** does many thing. They all work, so i won't annoy you with the full code. Just the end:

```
Intent intentToRepeat = new Intent(context, Caricamento.class);
                        intentToRepeat.putExtra(Costanti.string_notif_idcorso,notifica.getInt(Costanti.sp_notifiche_idcorso,0));
                        //set flag to restart/relaunch the app
                        intentToRepeat.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                        //Pending intent to handle launch of Activity in intent above
                        PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, NotificationHelper.ALARM_TYPE_RTC, intentToRepeat, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                        //Build notification
                        String titolonotifica = notifica.getString(Costanti.sp_notifiche_titolonotifica,"");
                        String subtitolo = notifica.getString(Costanti.sp_notifiche_subtitolo,"");
                        Notification repeatedNotification = buildLocalNotification(context, pendingIntent,titolonotifica,subtitolo).build();


                        //Send local notification
                        NotificationHelper.getNotificationManager(context).notify(NotificationHelper.ALARM_TYPE_RTC, repeatedNotification);

[...]

public NotificationCompat.Builder buildLocalNotification(Context context, PendingIntent pendingIntent, String titolo, String subtitolo) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;

    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "fisicamente")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icona_app)
            .setContentTitle(titolo)
            .setContentText(subtitolo)
            //.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
            //.bigText(testo))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_EVENT);

    return mBuilder;
}
```

So, the real issue should be in **NotificationHelper.java**:

```
public class NotificationHelper {
public static int ALARM_TYPE_RTC = 100;
private static AlarmManager alarmManager1;
private static PendingIntent alarmIntent1;

public static void scheduleRepeatingRTCNotification(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences pref_login = context.getSharedPreferences(Costanti.SP_LOGIN, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean primavolta = pref_login.getBoolean("primavolta",false);
//primavolta means first time
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    Random r1 = new Random();
    int casuale1 = r1.nextInt(100);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, casuale1);
    if (primavolta && calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())) calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
//I don't want to show the notification on the first login of the user, so i'm adding one day to the calendar.

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmDownload.class);
    alarmIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ALARM_TYPE_RTC, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager1.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 3 * AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent1);

}
```

This is what i do in **MainActivity.java**, the first time the user logs in:

```
Boolean primavolta = preferenze.getBoolean("primavolta",false);
    if (primavolta) {
        //Apre il drawer
        drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        //Notifiche
NotificationHelper.scheduleRepeatingRTCNotification(getApplicationContext());

    }
```

The drawer opens only during the first login, so the schedulerepeatingRTCNotification void doesn't fire more than once.

Any idea?

Thank you very much in advance!

Edited: there was a reference to a costant instead of 3 in the code.

Comment: It looks like the code is falling afoul of both issues mentioned here in the docs: "If the stated trigger time is in the past, the alarm will be triggered immediately. If there is already an alarm for this Intent scheduled (with the equality of two intents being defined by filterEquals(Intent)), then it will be removed and replaced by this one."

Comment: Tips: To avoid replacing the repeating alarm, this question may be helpful: [How to check if AlarmManager already has an alarm set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556670/how-to-check-if-alarmmanager-already-has-an-alarm-set). Also, it may be advisable to store the last successful sync time in SharedPreferences and set the next alarm based on that time.