# Alarm Pending intent returns null when app started again after killing from background

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, repeatingalarm

I am trying to check if a repeating alarm already exist. I am testing in MIUI 11 (OS v8.1) device, where i have set an alarm then removed the application from background. If i again opens the app a new alarm is created again

> Here is my code to set a repeating alarm

```
   private fun startAlarm() {
    val CUSTOM_INTENT = "com.test.intent.action.ALARM"
    val intent = Intent(this, AlarmHelper::class.java)
    intent.action = CUSTOM_INTENT
    val pendingIntent: PendingIntent =
        getBroadcast(this, 101, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    val alarmManager = getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
        System.currentTimeMillis()+60*60*1000, pendingIntent)
}
```

> This checks if an alarm already exist then i will not create a new one.

```
 private fun isAlarmExist() :Boolean =
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 101,
               Intent(this, AlarmHelper::class.java),
               PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null
```

> Already tried this

```
private fun isAlarmExist() :Boolean =
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 101,
               Intent("com.example.dozemodepoc.MY_UNIQUE_ACTION"),
               PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null

// this didnot work either
```

Already gone through
[How to check if AlarmManager already has an alarm set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556670/how-to-check-if-alarmmanager-already-has-an-alarm-set)

When force stopped the application and started the app again, new instance is again created. Any kind of help will be highly appreciated!!.

Comment: You should accept your answer. That will remove this question from the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a silly mistake in my isAlarmExist()

```
  private fun isAlarmExist() :Boolean {

    val CUSTOM_INTENT = "com.test.intent.action.ALARM"
    val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, AlarmHelper::class.java)
    intent.action = CUSTOM_INTENT

    return getBroadcast(this@MainActivity, 101, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE)!=null
}
```

This pending intent should be exact of the pending intent which was created when alarm was set up.