# Why wont this work android canceling Alarm?

Tags: android

This is what sets the alarm

```
    public void setSilent(Long taskId, Calendar when){
     Intent i = new Intent(mContext, SilentReceiver.class);
     PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 1 , i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
     mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

It takes in an id and date to use with the intent.
I am canceling it in another file when the user clicks delete. using

```
Intent i = new Intent(null, SilentReceiver.class);
         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(null, 1 , i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

should this work because it has the same request code as the first one or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Just curious, why is the first parameter to Intent null ? Also, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330522/how-to-cancel-this-repeating-alarm

Comment: check your PendingIntent [exists or not](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4556670/1342413)

Answer (score 1):

You have to save a reference to your first PendingIntent. This way you can use:

```
mAlarmManager.cancel(pi);
```

And the alarm should be cancelled.

This answer has been repeated many times. Please search before asking.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful to send a `PendingIntent` to stop the alarm with the same data than the `Intent` to create the alarm: [problem with cancel the alarm manager pending intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678092/problem-with-cancel-the-alarm-manager-pending-intent/7219859#7219859)